# Update-Database vs context.Database.Migrate() in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I understand from reading documents that the EF cli command `Update-Database` does the same as `context.Database.Migrate()` mentioned in

> Now you can update the database by either running "Update-Database" from the NuGet Package Manager Console or by running context.Database.Migrate().][1](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2020/02/12/ef-migrations.aspx)

However now I am getting an error

> Column name qqq in table 'xxxx' is specified more than once

The docs says to run the following EF cli

```
Add-Migration -IgnoreChanges
```

But however since I am using C# ... I am interested in knowing the `IgnoreChanges` version of `context.Database.Migrate();`

Let me know if I made myself clear : Thank you :)

Comment: context.Database.Migrate() will migrate the DB in production ...so i cant have CLI access of Product DB hence we are not using CLI but Migrate() function..

Comment: @marc_s besides editing you could also help in answering the issue